# Java Multithreading - Producer Consumer with limits

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to write the solution for Producer/Consumer but with limits.

**The producer(s) (**there may be more than one**) should terminate after producing a *total* of 5 values while the consumer(s) (there may be more than one consumer as well) should stop after all five values have been consumed.**

I have tried to use `AtomicInteger` for this:

```
public class InternalQueue {
    
    private static final int MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 10;
    
    private Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    
    public AtomicInteger itemsProduced = new AtomicInteger(0);
    
    public AtomicInteger itemsConsumed = new AtomicInteger(0);
        
    public synchronized boolean put(int n) {
        if(itemsProduced.get() < MAX_QUEUE_SIZE) {
            queue.add(n);
            itemsProduced.addAndGet(1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
}
```

**But the problem is how do I let the consumer thread to know when to stop ?**

I want to avoid exceptions.

There may be also multiple producers and multiple consumers.

Any better way to do this ?

Comment: It's not clear enough what you're trying to do. If you want to limit the producers, limit them, not the queue. You can also limit the queue, but then array of values would be enough for the underlying data structure. To let the consumer know there's no value left, you can return an `Optional` on get.

Comment: @daniu What I am trying to do is simply stop the producer and consumer after a threshold. The producers in total should not produce more than 5 values while consumers should not consume more than 5 values. Is it clear now ?

Comment: Well you haven't shown producer nor consumer, so I don't know what to tell you how to "stop" them. The boolean result on put should be enough for it to stop by itself, no? For consumer, it's not clear whether you want to distinguish between "no data that yet" and "there won't be any more data".

Comment: @daniu yes for consumers I have to distinguish between "no data that yet" and "there won't be any more data". For producers how do I distinguish between "queue is full" vs "I don't need to produce anymore".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this wrapper over `BlockingQueue`?

```java
public class MyQueue<T> {

    private final BlockingQueue<T> queue;
    private final AtomicInteger freeSpace;


    public MyQueue(int size) {
        this.freeSpace = new AtomicInteger(size);
        this.queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(size);
    }

    public boolean produce(T t) {
        if(isDone()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        freeSpace.decrementAndGet();
        return queue.offer(t);
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return freeSpace.get() <= 0;
    }

    public Optional<T> consume() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(queue.poll());
    }
}
```

Consumers could use the `isDone` method or could stop when the `Optional` returned by `consume` is empty. Note that `null` values are not accepted

Comment: `produce` will return `false` when the queue is full and no items needs to be produced anymore

Comment: One problem. Lets say `freeSpace` is `1` both `Producer1` and `Producer2`check the value of `isDone` to be true, they both proceed, 2 values are inserted, the consumer takes only one value and one value is left in the queue. **Anyway to avoid that erroneous insert ?**

Comment: Would you agree the only way is to put locks around `put` and `consume` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need your queue class to keep track of the number of items posted to the queue, as well as when the queue is empty or full. You also need to queue the requests of the producers so that only one producer at a time is given access to the queue.
The following Ada example demonstrates this. The solution is straightforward in Ada because Ada queues calls to protected object entries, ensuring only one producer or consumer has access at any given time.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   protected Limited_Buffer is
      entry Put(Item : in Integer);
      entry Get(Item : out Integer);
      function Is_New return Boolean;
      function At_Limit return Boolean;
   private
      Count : Natural := 0;
      Value : Integer;
      New_Value : Boolean := False;
   end Limited_Buffer;
   
   protected body Limited_Buffer is
      entry Put(Item : in Integer) when not New_Value and then not At_Limit is
      begin
         Value := Item;
         New_Value := True;
         Count := Count + 1;
      end Put;
      entry Get(Item : out Integer) when New_Value is
      begin
         Item := Value;
         New_Value := False;
      end Get;
      function Is_New return boolean is
      begin
         return New_Value;
      end Is_New;
      
      function At_Limit return Boolean is
      begin
         return Count >= 5;
      end At_Limit;
      
   end Limited_Buffer;
   
   task P1;
   
   task body P1 is
      Num : Integer := 1;
   begin
      loop
         select
            Limited_Buffer.Put(Num);
            Num := Num + 1;
         or
            delay 0.001;
         end select;
         exit when Limited_Buffer.At_Limit;
      end loop;
   end P1;
   
   task P2;
   
   task body P2 is
      Num : Integer := 10;
   begin
      loop
         select
            Limited_Buffer.Put(Num);
            Num := Num + 1;
         or
            delay 0.001;
         end select;
         exit when Limited_Buffer.At_Limit;
      end loop;
   end P2;
   
   task type C1;
   
   task body C1 is
      Num : Integer;
   begin
      loop
         select
         Limited_Buffer.Get(Num);
         Put_Line(Num'Image);
         or
            delay 0.001;
         end select;
         exit when Limited_Buffer.At_Limit;
      end loop;
   end C1;
   
   Con1, Con2 : C1;
             
begin
   null;
end Main;
```

Ada protected objects, such as Limited_Buffer in the example above, allow the definition of three kinds of methods: procedures, entries, and functions. Procedures provide an exclusive unconditional read-write lock on the protected object. Entries provide a conditional read-write lock on the protected object. Functions are read-only methods that provide a shared read lock on the protected object.
This example uses two entries named Put and Get as well as two functions named Is_New and At_Limit. The private portion of the protected object declaration defines the private data used by the protected object. In this example there are three data items within the protected object. Count is an instance of Natural, which is a pre-defined subtype of Integer with a minimum value of 0. Count is initialized to 0 in this example. Value is an instance of Integer. Value is the data element storing the value written to and read from the protected object by the Put and Get entries. New_Value is an instance of Boolean initialized to False. New_Value is used to ensure that each value written to the protected object is consumed exactly once.

The protected body Limited_Buffer implements the logic for the two entries and the two functions. Ada always separates the specifications and the implementations for protected objects and for tasks.
The first line of each entry mimics the protected object specification but also adds the boundary conditions. The entry is only evaluated when the boundary condition evaluates to TRUE. Each call by a task to an entry is queue. The default queuing policy is FIFO, ensuring that the calls are handled in the order the calls were made. The calling task is suspended while its call is in the entry queue. Each entry has its own queue.

The example goes on to create two producer tasks named P1 and P2. The only difference between the two tasks is the range of numbers they write to the queue.
We do not want the producers to be suspended in the Put entry queue forever when the Queue has processed it limit of values. Ada provides syntax for conditionally calling an entry queue. This syntax begins at the "select" reserved word. After the entry call completes the local variable Num is incremented. The conditional nature of the call begins at the "or" reserved word. The entry call is associated with a timer. If the time expires before the entry call completes the entry call is cancelled and the loop repeats. The loop is terminated when Limited_Buffer.At_Limit returns TRUE.

The two consumers are identical. I therefore created a task type for the consumers. Two instances of the task type are created later in the source code. The consumers repeatedly call Limited_Buffer.Get and print the value retrieved from the buffer. This activity is also done conditionally because we do not want the consumers to be suspended after all values have been read from the buffer.

Finally two instance of the consumer task type are create. All four tasks begin execution when the execution of the main procedure reaches the begin statement in the main procedure. The main procedure does nothing else, which is why its only executable statement is the null reserved word.

Comment: Why are you using Ada here ? The question is for Java.

Comment: Why not? The list of topics includes both multi-threading and producer-consumer.

Comment: The terminating conditions are the problem. Because one may have multiple producers and multiple consumers the terminating condition for a producer is finding the buffer is at its limit after either a successful or failed put attempt and the terminating condition for the consumers is finding the buffer is at its limit after a successful or failed get attempt. Expressing these conditions can be challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html):

> This is a classic "bounded buffer", in which a fixed-sized array holds elements inserted by producers and extracted by consumers. Once created, the capacity cannot be changed. Attempts to put an element into a full queue will result in the operation blocking; attempts to take an element from an empty queue will similarly block.